# Concatenated SELECT * results

Tags: mysql

How do I concatenate the results of a SELECT * query?

I can use this to SELECT *all* and then create an additional concatenated attribute, but I don't know how to concatenate the returned attributes alone.

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(Cust_FName, ' ', Cust_LName) AS Cust_Name
FROM Customer_Information AS Customers
```

Produces:

> Cust_ID, Cust_FName, Cust_LName, Cust_Name

But I want to use a SELECT *all* and get:

> Cust_ID, Cust_Name

Comment: Can't you just do `SELECT Cust_ID, CONCAT(Cust_FName, ' ', Cust_LName) AS Cust_Name`?

Comment: `SELECT *` outputs all fields "as is".  You cannot get any customization, when you use this option.  So don't use it in your query.

Comment: please provide your db schema, some data sample and expected result

Answer (score 0):

If all that you want in the output is

```
Cust_ID, Cust_Name
```

Then the following should work

```
SELECT Cust_ID, CONCAT(Cust_FName, ' ', Cust_LName) AS Cust_Name
FROM Customer_Information AS Customers;
```

EDIT:

Nested SELECT for funzies

```
SELECT Cust_ID, CONCAT(Cust_FName, ' ', Cust_LName) AS Cust_Name
FROM (SELECT * FROM Customer_Information AS Customers);
```

Comment: Ya, that's what I've been thinking, but it's for school and the question says that I need to SELECT all and then concatenate those two fields. I've been scouring my textbook/internet and I can only see the way that you mentioned. I'm thinking that maybe the question is worded poorly, but I don't know.

Comment: As far as I know there is not a way to "remove" columns from a query. You  could do a nested SELECT though (see above edit).